# non www to www redirection inside folder redirects 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I'm redirecting all non www urls to www. for that i've used the following htaccess rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

for most of the urls its working, except this one:

```
example.com/admin/stats.php
```

stats.php placed inside admin folder. [ /public_html/admin/ ]. When i try above url it returns **404 not found** and the redirected url is `www.example.com/401.shtml`

**other redirects in the same htaccess files**

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ predicts.php?cn=$1&dte=$2 [L] 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ index.php?cn=$1 
RewriteRule ^prediction/([0-9]*)/(.*)/?$ common.php?pid=$1  [L] 
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/?$ profile.php?id=$1  [L]
```

So what is the issue here? Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks!.

Comment: what other rewriterules do you have?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey i've update those rules in my edit. pls, check it

Comment: Where does this `.htaccess` reside? Do you have any other rewrites in admin folder's `htaccess`?

Comment: Is your admin folder `auth` secured? I mean do you need to enter a `username/password` to gain access? Also, do you have a `401.shtml`? URL gets redirected to this when `HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized` occurs.

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey No, There is no htaccess file inside 'admin' directory and i'm not protected with any htaccess passwork

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey Great, previously i had htaccess file and secured that directory using htpasswd. when i posted question here i renamed those files, thinking that i won't use that htaccess. That is reason i said 'NO' when asked about 'auth' secured or not. but now i removed those files completely and cleared my cache and it worked properly. Thanks for your effort, can you post it as an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: Welcome. Good to know it worked out. Have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `admin` folder `auth` secured? I mean do you need to enter a `username/password` to gain access? Also, do you have a `401.shtml`? URL gets redirected to this when `HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized occurs`.

Comment: htaccess inside the admin folder  caused the issue, now i removed it and it working...